# copy paste various files using dired on emacs while using ido.el

Tags: emacs, copy, dired, ido-mode, ido

I'm using emacs with dired,

```
(require 'dired-details)
(dired-details-install)
```

and ido,

```
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
(setq ido-everywhere t)
(ido-mode 1)

(setq ido-use-filename-at-point 'guess)
(setq ido-create-new-buffer 'always)
```

(as well as recentf as described [here](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2011/01/27/find-files-faster-recent-files-package/))

However, when I'm in dired and do copy (Shift-C) after selecting a few files,
and go to the new directory where they should be pasted ... I have two non-working options:
1) either I click on a directory and go a level further into a directory I don't want.
2) I click on a file and
ido complains

> Marked Copy: target must be a
>   directory:

How can I make dired paste the selected files to the new destination?
Any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try C-j once you are in the target directory in ido. Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem here is that while there's a `read-file-name-function` which `ido` can attach itself to, there's no `read-directory-name-function`, `ido-mode` has no explicit support for this feature of `dired`, and there's nothing about the `read-file-name` invocation I could figure out that `ido-mode` could hook onto.

All I can suggest is to just turn off `ido` by using `C-f`.  The invocation of `read-file-name` by dired is so many levels deep that it wouldn't even be particularly elegant to patch:

```
* read-file-name("Copy <file> to: " "<dir>/" "<dir>/<file>")
  apply(read-file-name ("Copy <file> to: " "<dir>/" "<dir>/<file>"))
  dired-mark-pop-up(nil copy ("<file>") read-file-name "Copy <file> to: " "<dir>/" "<dir>/<file>")
  dired-mark-read-file-name("Copy %s to: " "<dir>/" copy nil ("<file>") "<dir>/<file>")
  dired-do-create-files(copy dired-copy-file "Copy" nil 67 nil nil)
  dired-do-copy(nil)
```

Comment: Thank you Nicholas for the insight.  I guess I'll just have to C-f to switch off when doing these file operations.